# Mass counterterms in Yukawa-type meson-nucleon theory (Coleman's notes)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, mesons

On page 102 of his QFT notes (https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013) Coleman uses the following reasoning for calculating the counterterms to the meson and nucleon masses  in what he calls "quantum mesodynamics" (essentially scalar Yukawa theory but with a complex KG field instead of a Dirac fermion).

[image: screenshot from page 102]

This seems incorrect - the $\psi \psi^\dagger \phi$ interaction term allows (for examples) meson pair-production into a nucleon + antinucleon pair like

$\phi \to \psi + \overline{\psi}$

so one-meson states should be able to scatter into final states that aren't also one-meson states. Is the correct statement here "one-meson states $| \vec{q}' \rangle$ should never scatter as long as $|\vec{q}'|$ is small enough to forbid pair production" ? That seems more correct, and I think that weaker assumption (plus the analogous statement for nucleons) suffices for the calculation of $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering matrix elements of the form $\langle \vec{q} | S | \vec{q}' \rangle$, Coleman is considering processes in which a single meson enters and a single meson exits. You're completely correct that there are pair production processes; but the initial and final states must contain single mesons.

If you were to calculate the $S$ matrix elements listed, you would consider Feynman diagrams containing intermediate pair production and annihilation processes. All of these will contribute to the [self energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy) of the particle, which would renormalize the mass in the absence of counterterms. Coleman is saying that the method to determine the counterterm coefficients $b$ and $c$ is to compute the mass of the particle, including the self-energy corrections and counterterms, and demand that they are equal to the physical masses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see my mistake now: If you take the equation that Coleman writes for meson scattering and integrate both sides against

\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^3 q | \vec{q} \rangle
\end{equation*}

then by the appropriate Fock-space notion of completeness Coleman's equation just says that \begin{equation*}

S | \vec{q}' \rangle = | \vec{q}' \rangle + \Delta

\end{equation*} 

where the correction term $\Delta$ has no component along in the one-meson sector of the Hilbert space.

Comment: Actually, now I'm not so sure: If you take the equation \begin{equation*}
S |\vec{q}' \rangle = |\vec{q}' \rangle
\end{equation*}
and compute the norm of both sides, using the facts that $|\vec{q}' \rangle$ is orthogonal to $\Delta$ and $S$ is unitary, we get \begin{equation*}
\langle \Delta, \Delta \rangle = 0.
\end{equation*}
and we're back to my original objection. I still suspect that the correct resolution is that this identity only needs to hold for sufficiently small $\vec{q}' \in \mathbb{R}^3$.